# FTP Connection in app.config

Tags: c#, ftp, connection, app-config

I want to connect to a FTP server inside my C# code, and I want to store FTP server, user and password inside my app.config. I do not want to store it in a different file and neither hardcode the ftp inside my C#.

How do I do that?

I know about connectionStrings but so far I have used it only with SQL, not FTP, and I do not know how to make it work with FTP. So far I haven't found any answer on how to put ftp info inside app.config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add something like this to your web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="FTP_URL" value="" />
    <add key="USER" value="" />
    <add key="PASS" value="" />
</appSettings>
```

and then in you c# code get it like this

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTP_URL"];
```